# Tuning And Performance

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

```
INSERT INTO <TABLED>
SELECT A.* FROM 
<TABLEA> A  WHERE A.MED_DTL_STATUS='0' 
AND A.TRANS_ID
NOT IN 
(      
  SELECT DISTINCT TRANS_ID_X_REF FROM <TABLEB>
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT TRANS_ID FROM <TABLEA> WHERE ADJUSTMENT_TYPE='3' 
);
```

The table has more than 250 columns.
The Select statement will return more than 300000 records .The above query is running for a long time.I have never worked on performance tuning.Could someone please help me on tuning this or give me some good links on how to tune oracle queries?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tuning, in general, is a topic of many, many books...  The simplest starting point, though, would be to generate and post a query  plan.  Tell us what indexes are available.  Tell us how selective your predicates are.  Are the cardinality estimates in your query plan approximately correct?  If not, are your statistics accurate?

Comment: Have a look at the query plan in what ever tool you use, see what it says. How often are you doing this?

Comment: I`m not using any indexes.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Twice in a month.

Comment: Well some indexes would be a good start though given you only do it twice a month, more than a cursory effort would seem a waste of resources...

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: As a very general advice remove the distinct. Union returns distinct rows. The Distinct slows down the performance. Check your query - Table A referenced in main query and in union. You can restrict your ADJUSTMENT_TYPE in main query I think, which will return less records and make it faster. Run your query with small amount of rows to test using the Rownum and see how it performs. As others suggested Indexes, Explain Plan and Autotrace may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that NOT IN clauses are really slow. I would rewrite the query with NOT EXISTS instead.

```
INSERT INTO <TABLED>
SELECT A.* FROM <TABLEA> A  
WHERE A.MED_DTL_STATUS='0' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT B.TRANS_ID_X_REF 
    FROM <TABLEB> B 
    WHERE B.TRANS_ID_X_REF = A.TRANS_ID
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT A2.TRANS_ID 
    FROM <TABLEA> A2 
    WHERE A2.TRANS_ID = A.TRANS_ID
    AND A2.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE='3'
);
```

The query above assumes there are indexes on TRANS_ID on TableA and TableB. This may not really solve your problem, but without knowing the data model and indexes it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the good suggestions already given, whenever you are inserting a large number of records into a table it is best practice to drop the indexes on that table.  When the INSERT process has finished, then recreate the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

How selective is this predicate?

```
A.MED_DTL_STATUS='0'
```

If it filters out a large proportion of the rows in the table then creating an index on MED_DTL_STATUS might help.

Note that Oracle has (or at least used to have) a limit of ~1000 items for IN: in case your subquery starts returning more rows than that you will get an error (this IN can be rewritten using a left outer join if/when that happens).

Comment: A.MED_DTL_STATUS='0' has more than 200000 records on each load.